# WCF service with both basicHttpBinding and netTcpBinding; can't access HTTP endpoint

Tags: .net, wcf, wsdl, wcf-binding, wcf-configuration

I want to make available the same interface with a netTcpBinding and basicHttpBinding. I also wanna make available the wsdl for both endpoints. When I access `http://localhost:9876/TestService/`, I get the mex endpoint that has the information for the Tcp endoint at `http://localhost:9876/TestService/?wsdl`, but the address `http://localhost:9876/TestService/ws` does not respond, and I can't understand why. I have the base address, and the relative address. Can someone lend me a hand pointing out what's missing? Right now, I'm just trying to get working the TestImplementation service, and I haven't messed with the MessaginImplementation service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="SimpleBinding" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="DefaultTCPBinding" transactionFlow="true" />
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MetadataBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetBinding="webHttpBinding"
                        httpGetBindingConfiguration="" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior" name="CompanyX.AppServer.Implementation.TestImplementation">
                <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultTCPBinding"
                    name="TestTCPEndpoint" contract="CompanyX.AppServer.Interfaces.ITest" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                    name="TestMex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <endpoint address="/ws" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SimpleBinding"
                    name="Test" contract="CompanyX.AppServer.Interfaces.ITest" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9878/TestService" />
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9876/TestService/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior" name="CompanyX.AppServer.Implementation.MessaginImplementation">
                <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultTCPBinding"
                    name="MessagingTCPEndpoint" contract="CompanyX.AppServer.Interfaces.IMessaging" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                    name="MessagingMex" contract="CompanyX.AppServer.Interfaces.IMessaging" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9878/MessagingService" />
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9876/MessagingService" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a rookie mistake on my part. It's actually correct. The answer is in [the post below](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/38fd2e58-85b3-42c6-955b-323cd0a922f2).
I only get a response from the browser when I hit the base HTTP class, but using this wsdl, I can connect with both bindings.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your service endpoint address is wrong:

```
<endpoint address="/ws" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SimpleBinding"
                name="Test" contract="CompanyX.AppServer.Interfaces.ITest" />
```

Since it's a relative address (added to your base address), it should be just `ws` - no leading forward slash:

```
<endpoint name="Test" 
          address="ws" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SimpleBinding"
          contract="CompanyX.AppServer.Interfaces.ITest" />
```

Try it without the forward slash! Should work that way.

Comment: I tried without it, but I don't get an answer back neither. I got that from this Microsoft link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733749.aspx

Comment: @Pascal: not sure if the trailing slash in your base address might cause an issue: `<add baseAddress="http://localhost:9876/TestService/" />` - try it without it - any change??

Comment: sorry for wasting your time. It's a rookie WCF mistake. I posted the answer below for future reference of anyone having the same doubts as I had in the future. Thank you soooo much!